# error: SchemaError(aws.k8s.networking.v1alpha1.PolicyEndpoint): invalid object doesn't have additional properties

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-eks

following https://medium.com/avmconsulting-blog/deploying-a-kubernetes-cluster-with-amazon-eks-9455e7e7828 document for EKS setup but on kubectl apply -f aws-auth-cm.yaml, getting below error:
error: SchemaError(aws.k8s.networking.v1alpha1.PolicyEndpoint): invalid object doesn't have additional properties

I didn't find any solution online

Comment: What version of EKS are you deploying? It sounds like your template is trying to install the VPC CNI addon, but it passing in the wrong properties. If you run `aws eks describe-addon-configuration --addon-name vpc-cni --addon-version <version>` it will output the schema for the configuration.

Comment: If it's not the addon, then look at the schema for the CRD that VPC CNI uses, https://github.com/aws/amazon-vpc-cni-k8s/blob/3cd2b31e8be5cd9957d32c476ee426697a84cf09/charts/aws-vpc-cni/crds/customresourcedefinition.yaml#L42-L251.